# PHP Array.length for a two dimensional array (y axis)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use a function whereby I see how tall (y axis) a two dimensional array is in PHP. How would you suggest that I do this? Sorry, I am new to PHP.

Comment: @phihag gives a very elegant solution... there are no truly 2-dimensional arrays in PHP, the 'array of the array' can be any length, so you would have to get the largest 'array of array'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
max(array_map('count', $array2d))
```

Answer (score 4):

If the y-axis is the outer array, then really just `count($array)`. The second dimension would just be `count($array[0])` if it's uniform.

Answer (score 3):

A multi-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays -- it's not like you've blocked out a rectangular set of addresses; more like a train where each car can be stacked as high as you like.

As such, the "height" of the array, presumably, is the count of the currently largest array member.  @phihag has given a great way to get that (`max(array_map(count, $array2d))`) but I just want to be sure you understand what it means.  The max height of the various arrays within the parent array has no effect on the size or capacity of any given array member.

Comment: When we start to talk about 2D array's dimensions, I'd propose sticking with the mathematical equivalent of a matrix, where height -number of rows- is usually considered the first dimension and width -number of columns- the second one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$max = 0;

foreach($array as $val){
 $max = (count($val)>$max?count($val):$max)
}
```

where $max is the count you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

In my application I have used this approach.

```
$array = array();

$array[0][0] = "one";
$array[0][1] = "two";

$array[1][0] = "three";
$array[1][1] = "four";

for ($i=0; isset($array[$i][1]); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i][1];
}
```

> output: twofour

Probably, this is not the best approach for your application, but for mine it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the second dimension, use `count` in a loop:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($var AS $value) {
    $counter += count($value);
}

echo $counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.dimension:

```
count($arr);
```

2.dimension:

```
function count2($arr) {
  $dim = 0;

  foreach ($arr as $v) {
    if (count($v) > $dim)
      $dim = count($v);
  }

  return $dim;
}
```

As it is possible to have each array / vector of different length (unlike a mathematical matrix) you have to look for the max. length.